# how to run anaconda python without installing on windows system? Is der any On Demand online cloud environment is available like SAS Studio?

Tags: python, pandas, installation, anaconda

I have to work on Pandas in Jupyter Notebook but I cannt install Python (using Anaconda) or any other packages. Please, help me out. Iam looking for a cloud environment where I can practice on Pandas/Python easily

Comment: ssh into a server where you *can* install Python? I'm not sure what else you are expecting if you can't install Python.

Comment: You can try using https://try.jupyter.org/

Answer (score 1):

Try https://notebooks.azure.com

It is a free service that provides Jupyter notebooks (runs Anaconda Python) along with supporting libraries as a service.

For further details visit [FAQ](https://notebooks.azure.com/faq)

Comment: This service have shut down. Try alternatives at https://notebooks.azure.com/Content/alternatives.html.

Answer (score 1):

https://cocalc.com
Try this, no sign up required.
Start coding straight away!

Comment: That's the one available in Dec 2020. MS's AN has shut down, and Jupyter's doesn't have some libraries. (e.g. jieba and wordcloud)

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of such services. I use pythonanywhere; and it allows users to host apps as well.

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/

Comment: You can use Python on PythonAnywhere of course, but specifically Anaconda is not currently supported there.

Comment: This is true; but Jupyter is there plus batch runs.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it myself but:

https://wakari.io

Comment: It is redirecting to anaconda. will u pls, take time to tell me in a step wise manner to get access on to a new notebook. Thanks !

Comment: Oh wow, it looks like anaconda absorbed it into their "Enterprise Notebooks". Based on the site it looks like they have cloud notebooks. But you might have to pay. I would email them and ask for the functionality that used to be on wakari and see what they say.